# sharer.php - multiple URLs

Tags: facebook, url, iframe

After having searched for several hours, I have not been able to find an answer to this question. I am currently using sharer.php to achieve a simple "share link" post on facebook i.e.:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://mywebsiteapp.com/product.php?prodID=1

What i have in my application is a series of checkboxes with items. I check the items that i would like to share and click "Share" and a window opens for each item.

I would like to share these items on Facebook within one window, rather than having them open up in a new one. This is how i currently have it. It would be incredibly tedious for users to go through each window and click "share" for each one.

I was thinking of combining all the windows into separate iframes on one page. However, Facebook does not allow iframes to be used or any sort of embedding code, so i am out of options.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook's JavaScript API.  It will at least allow your users to share all of the items without leaving the page, although they will still have to go through them sequentially.

I think Facebook's JavaScript API actually does put each Facebook page in an iframe, which is fine because it's Facebook doing it and not you.

Comment: Facebook's JavaScript API actually puts it in a popup window, in Chrome anyway. Guess there's no other way other than sequentially selecting them? other than to use an app...?

Comment: I think you can do something with OAuth where you ask your user for permission to share as much stuff on their wall as you want.  I haven't really looked into it, however.